# error proxy on install npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I was looking for solutions to this problem in google.com, I read all related issues on this topic at stackoverflow.com. But the right answer is not found.
The problem is that for every command `npm install -g` (`npm` or `yo` or `bower`) go here such error:

```
C:\Users\User>npm install -g yo
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7

npm ERR! Invalid protocol: 192.168.10.1:
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\npm-debug.log
```

Installed operating system: Windows 7 (x86) Corporate.
Installed version Node.JS: 4.2.1 .
The content npm-debug.log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'yo' ]
2 info using npm@2.14.7
3 info using node@v4.2.1
4 verbose install initial load of C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\package.json
5 verbose readDependencies loading dependencies from C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\package.json
6 silly cache add args [ 'yo', null ]
7 verbose cache add spec yo
8 silly cache add parsed spec Result {
8 silly cache add   raw: 'yo',
8 silly cache add   scope: null,
8 silly cache add   name: 'yo',
8 silly cache add   rawSpec: '',
8 silly cache add   spec: '*',
8 silly cache add   type: 'range' }
9 silly addNamed yo@*
10 verbose addNamed "*" is a valid semver range for yo
11 silly addNameRange { name: 'yo', range: '*', hasData: false }
12 silly mapToRegistry name yo
13 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
14 silly mapToRegistry registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
15 silly mapToRegistry uri http://registry.npmjs.org/yo
16 verbose addNameRange registry:http://registry.npmjs.org/yo not in flight; fetching
17 verbose request uri http://registry.npmjs.org/yo
18 verbose request no auth needed
19 info attempt registry request try #1 at 16:59:12
20 verbose request id 4545121454874541214
21 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/yo
22 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: Invalid protocol: 192.168.10.1:
23 info attempt registry request try #2 at 16:59:22
24 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/yo
25 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: Invalid protocol: 192.168.10.1:
26 info attempt registry request try #3 at 17:00:22
27 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/yo
28 verbose stack Error: Invalid protocol: 192.168.10.1:
28 verbose stack     at Request.init (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:461:31)
28 verbose stack     at new Request (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:140:8)
28 verbose stack     at request (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:55:10)
28 verbose stack     at CachingRegistryClient.makeRequest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:149:13)
28 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:66:17
28 verbose stack     at RetryOperation._fn (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\attempt.js:18:5)
28 verbose stack     at null._onTimeout (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\retry\lib\retry_operation.js:49:10)
28 verbose stack     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
29 verbose cwd C:\Users\User
30 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
31 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo"
32 error node v4.2.1
33 error npm  v2.14.7
34 error Invalid protocol: 192.168.10.1:
35 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
35 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
36 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Why leave such a mistake? What's the problem here? How to solve this problem? Thank you in advance for help

My computer connects Internet through a proxy server. By this, I changed the configuration npm on:

```
 npm config set http-proxy http://192.168.10.1:3128
 npm config set https-proxy https://192.168.10.1:3128
 npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
 npm config set strict-ssl=false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is my solution

```
npm config set http-proxy http://192.168.10.1
```

Comment: `npm config set http` worked and `http-proxy` not

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while installing native scripts. Try using the following commands:

1. `set http`
2. `set http_proxy=`

This will help you.